# How to change date format in digikam (day/month/year instead of month/day/year)

Tags: date, digikam

In Digikam, is it possible to change the default date format (e.g. in the EXIF metadata) to day/month/year, instead of month/day/year?

Comment: Is it locale US?

Comment: Which operating system? I couldn't find a digikam specific setting, so it looks like it might pick up the OS settings. Mine's running on Ubuntu with UK locale, so is already day/month/year.

Comment: This is how it works on my system.. (Ubuntu with locale=en_IE.UTF-8)

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere thanks, it is as you say! Post it as an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: @Fabio - done. Let me know any suggested edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's no specific setting in DigiKam - the software will use the date format as set in the operating system.

Comments from Romeo Ninov and xenoid have the answer - this will be determined by the "locale" settings (Linux/Windows/Mac). There are different ways to check and change these based on which operating system is running - I'd suggest a search for the operating system installed.